# Erro em método: removerEditoraAnterior

Tags: java

sou iniciante em Java, e estou tendo um erro em um método da classe Editar ,pra remover a editora. O método para remover um autor funciona perfeitamente com a mesma lógica, já no método remover editora ele dá esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

**Classe Biblioteca, contendo os métodos de remover Autor e Editora**

```
    public void removerAutorAnterior(Autor codigo) {

        autores.remove(codigo);
    }


    public void removerEditoraAnterior(Editora codigo) {

     editora.remove(codigo);
    }
```

**Classe Editar**

```
case 1:{


    Autor AtorAnterior=biblioteca.pesquisarAutor(codigo);

    System.out.println("Digite o código do autor que deseja editar:");
    AtorAnterior.setCodigo(scannerNumerico.nextInt());


    if(AtorAnterior==null){
    System.out.println("Error: autor não encontrado");
   }

    else{
    System.out.println("Autor encontrado:"+AtorAnterior.getNome());

    Autor Autornovo= new Autor();

    System.out.println("Digite um novo nome:");
    Autornovo.setNome(scannerString.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Digite um novo email:");
    Autornovo.setEmail(scannerString.nextLine());

    biblioteca.removerAutorAnterior(AtorAnterior); **irá remover o autor anterior**

   biblioteca.cadastarAutor(Autornovo); **irá cadastrar o novo autor**
        }
            break;
        }
```

É nessa parte onde está o erro no método:**biblioteca.removerEditoraAnterior(EditoraAnterior):**

```
    //Editar Editora
        case 2:{


            Editora EditoraAnterior=biblioteca.pesquisarEditora(codigo);

            System.out.println("Digite o código da editora que deseja editar:");
             EditoraAnterior.setCodigo(scannerNumerico.nextInt());

            if( EditoraAnterior==null){
                System.out.println("Error: Editora não encontrada");
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("Editora encontrada:"+ EditoraAnterior.getNome());

                Editora EditoraNova= new Editora();

                System.out.println("Digite os novos dados:\n");

                System.out.println("Digite novo nome:");
                EditoraNova.setNome(scannerNumerico.nextLine());

                System.out.println("Digite o novo cnpj");
                EditoraNova.setCnpj(scannerNumerico.nextInt());

                biblioteca.removerEditoraAnterior(EditoraAnterior);
                biblioteca.cadastrarEditora(EditoraNova);

            break;  
            }

            }
```

Comment: Eu estou começando a questionar a sanidade da sua IDE, dado o contexto de problemas que ela já apresentou. Limpa a área e manda fazer um build limpo

Comment: Concordo com o amigo acima, acho que seu eclipse está meio bugado, ou existe mais um projeto no eclipse que está conflitando com esse. Já verificou o build Path?

Comment: Cara, não coloca-se chaves depois de um `case` ._.

Comment: Amigo sempre usei chaves depois dos cases, e nunca deu problema algum , creio que o erro ñ é por causa disso

Comment: Eu sou iniciante em Java/Eclipse, não sei limpar  a área , fazer build, verifciar build Patch ou algo desse tipo ainda ._.

Answer (score 0):

Cara pode ser que seja erro no seu eclipse mesmo. Mas esse código ai ta muito estranho. Tenta alimentar essa variável ***codigo*** com um valor q não existe. Depois tenta executar essa linha `EditoraAnterior.setCodigo(scannerNumerico.nextInt());`
Não tem como funcionar isso cara, como tu vai setar um valor pra um objeto nulo? Vai dar NullPointerException tem q colocar esse teste `if( EditoraAnterior==null)` depois da linha `Editora EditoraAnterior=biblioteca.pesquisarEditora(codigo);`

```
   Editora EditoraAnterior=biblioteca.pesquisarEditora(codigo);

   System.out.println("Digite o código da editora que deseja editar:");
   EditoraAnterior.setCodigo(scannerNumerico.nextInt());

   if( EditoraAnterior==null){
       System.out.println("Error: Editora não encontrada");
   }
```